# How to display live image fetched by Json on android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I am using 3 tabs and shrelock actionbar in my app.
3 tab having 3 fragments. on 1st fragment i want to show Image live song play image.
So I am fetching URL by parsing JSON file. And than I display on image view.

To display image I have used two method one is Async-task to fetch and display. Another way is simple method in which you assign image to image view.

Now problem is when I scroll tabs and again go back to that fragment in which I am fetching image it taks time as follows.

1) In Async_task = when I swap tabs and again go back to home tab I scrolls easily but it takes 5sec delay to display image because I have assign URL to imageviewer in post execute method.

2) simple method without using Async task is direct assign URL to image view.. in which when i scroll between tabs and move back to home tab it takes time to swich back to home tab(fragments) May be because it parse JSON and than assign image URL so.

My problem is I want it to loaded already..or loaded once and use it unto lifecycle of android.. But it should change image when I got different URL from JSON parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to cache the images after you retrieve them. That way, you don't have to re-accesss the URL to display the images again. You just have to re-displayed the already downloaded and optimized image.

Google has a portion of their documentation dedicated to how to handle images within Android. It also gives you sample code (BitmapFun.zip). [You should check that out.](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html)

You should also check Jake Wharton's [LruCache implementation](https://github.com/JakeWharton/DiskLruCache). Great way to cache the images.